# SED: First and last empty lines not removed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, newline

I'm running the following but it's returning with empty lines at the top and bottom of the new file.

How do I output to a new file without these empty lines?

```
input | sed -E '/^$/d' > file.txt
```

The following has no effect either.

```
sed '1d'  
sed '$d'
```

I'm unsure of where the expression has problems.

Comment: This works for me, not sure what you're doing wrong: `sed '/^$/d' <<< $'\n\none\ntwo\nthree\n\n'`

Comment: What does your input look like? The only thing that I can see with your sed expression is that it should be -e rather than -E...

Comment: Perhaps your input `file.txt` has "empty lines" of spaces? what about `'/^ *$/d'` as your regex?

Comment: How are you detecting that the first and last lines are not being deleted?  Is there any possibility that you have CRLF line endings, in which case the CR would make it appear non-empty and hence not eligible for deletion.

Comment: @BartonChittenden On Mac OS X, `-E` indicates to use an ERE instead of a BRE. It's an extension analogous to the `-r` flag extension in GNU sed. Makes no difference here, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The `-E` option is undocumented (I found it by reading the source code).  It's synonymous with `-r`.  The use of `-E` is meant for compatibility with BSD `sed`.  As @MichaelJ.Barber says, it makes no difference here; `-e` would be more portable and less obscure.

Comment: Are *any* empty lines deleted?  The undeleted lines could have CRLF line endings, as @JonathanLeffler suggests, or they could just have space or tab characters.  `cat -A file.txt` or `cat -v file.txt` should show you what's actually on those lines.

Comment: @KeithThompson `-E` is only undocumented for GNU sed: cf. the Mac OS X (man page)[http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sed/osx-10.6.php]. It's not obscure at all there. Sadly, portable sed really requires the *very* limited POSIX BREs - which should work here, of course. (Not that we know that the OP cares about portability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable using `awk` then this would work -

```
awk 'NF' INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep . file_name > outfile` would do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 echo -e " \t\r\nsomething\n \t \r\n" | sed '/^\s*$/d' | cat -n
 1  something
```

N.B. This removes *all* blank lines, to preserve blank lines in the body of a file use:

```
echo -e " \t\r\n   something\n \nsomething else \n \t \r\n" | 
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^\(\s*\n\)*\|\(\s*\n\)*$//g'
   something

something else
```